# pass variable to every controller Using the Registry in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

Can I use zend Registry to save variable to use in other controller?
this is my code that don't work in another controller:

Zend_Registry::set('id', $Id);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Zend_Registry` is an alternative to the old school `$GLOBALS`. It's a container, you put stuff in there, and will retrieve them later on.

Where do you put `id` in registry? In the `Bootstrap`? `init`? Make sure it's called in your application flow.

Comment: I put it somewhere in action not in int or bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you expect zend_registry to work like a cookie witch it does'nt. If you set something in a controller then click some link to another controller you will have lost that data. 
Otherwise like shadowfax said just make sure you set your data somewhere in the application flow.